# What's the digit sum of $4444^{4444}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

For a natural number $n$ say that $d(n)$ is the sum of the digits of $n$ (in base $10$). Then what is the value of $$d(d(d(4444^{4444}))) ?$$
 I have been trying with modular arithmetic, but can't do it.

Comment: Thinking about that problem makes my head spin.

Comment: It may help to notice that $d(4444^2)=40$.

Comment: The answer is supposed to be $7$; on the first iteration, it is $72601$; on the second, $16$.

Comment: If you search MSE under 4444, you will find the question has been asked several times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the sum of digits function is essentially a logarithm-for a reasonable mix of digits $d(n)\approx 4.5 \log_{10}(n)$  Also, the sum of digits maintains the value $\pmod 9$.  So if you can compute $4444^{4444} \pmod 9$, then convince yourself that $d(d(d(4444^{4444}))) \lt 10$ you are home.

Comment: Is this really true? What about $d(9)=9 \ne 0 = d(9) \pmod 9$?

Comment: It is  $4444^{4444}\mod 9$. As $4444\equiv 7\mod 9$ and $7$ has order $3$ modulo $9$, we have  that:
$$4444^{4444}\equiv 7^{4444}=7^{4444\mod 3}=7^1=7\mod 9.$$

Comment: @gammatester:  yes, you have to use $9$ as the value for multiples of $9$, not $0$